# How to get back the application menu for LibreOffice after an update? 

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

I do not have the menu bar of LibreOffice in the top panel of my Unity desktop (the Global Menu functionality). Though I have installed `lo-menubar`.

Those are the characteristics of my system:

- Ubuntu 11.04.
- LibreOffice 3.3.3 installed from the appropriate [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa).
- lo-menubar 0.1.1~pre1-0ubuntu2.

How do I fix it?

Comment: As far as I know, the latest LO is supposed to support Unity menu by default.

Comment: @Oxwivi : LibreOffice doesn't support unity global menu by default , see [OMG!UBUNTU!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-enable-global-menu-support-for-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-11-04/)

Comment: @binarylife, that applies to the LO version shipped with Natty. Unless I'm much mistaken, I read that latest release has panel menu support by default.

Comment: @Oxwivi , sorry maybe you meant that the latest version is 3.4? If so yes it supports the Global menu. We were talking about the version `3.3.3` in this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa) .

Comment: @binarylife, my bad, I did not notice that PPA was behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works now simply by removing the `lo-menubar` package and installing it again :

`sudo apt-get remove lo-menubar`

Then

`sudo apt-get install lo-menubar`

---

**Why this happend?**

As I suppose the `lo-menubar` is like a plugin for libreOffice. When you updated the program, the plugin needs to be re-installed, this solution worked for me after trying it.

**And this must be done when you install this package by the above command :**

```
 Synchronizing repository for bundled extensions



  Enabling: menubar
   Enabling: Jobs.xcu
   Enabling: menubar.uno.so

unopkg done.
```

This what I can explain for now.

Comment: It worked. If you can explain me why, I would be thankful to you. However I now have a new problem : the icon set has been changed into a "legacy" one, looking like OpenOffice.org. But I'll open a new question for this.

Comment: @Agmenor : Answer updated. And for the icons , yes it is better to ask another question.

Comment: @binarylife : thank you very much. Here is the new question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/51118/why-does-libreoffice-use-openoffice-org-like-icons .

Comment: @Agmenor: You are welcome.

Comment: This solution is not working for me, even after a restart. I am running the 64bit version of Natty, might this make a difference? Any ideas?

Comment: @geoffrey : I personally tested this solution only on 32-bit version, and it worked well. But in your case I don't think it will matter. Are you using the latest version 3.3.3 form this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa)?

Comment: @binarylife yes, I'm using that PPA, same version of LO and lo-menubar as in the question above. I'll probably have to downgrade LO to 3.3.2

Comment: @geoffrey: Or [3.4.1](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/libreoffice-3-4-1-released-sees-bugfixes/) ;) , which has the global menu by default.