# Why does LibreOffice use OpenOffice.org-like icons?

Tags: icons, libreoffice, openoffice.org

After having solved [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51102/why-havent-i-the-menu-bar-of-libreoffice-in-the-top-panel-even-if-i-have-install/51107#51107) by uninstalling and installing `lo-menubar`, I got a weird bug in LibreOffice. The icons now look like the ones of the legacy OpenOffice.org which is not installed on my computer.

[image: Surprisingly ugly icons in LibreOffice]

Can you help me solve this problem?

Those are the characteristics of my system:

- Ubuntu 11.04,
- LibreOffice 3.3.3 installed from the appropriate [PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu).

Comment: I don't know why, but the icons are the same for me, see this [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6L8iQ.png).

Comment: Since OpenOffice is the root of LibreOffice, are you sure, they changed the icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the tango icon theme selected (this not a legacy Open-Office theme by the way). Also I found that LibreOffice seems to force certain themes if your GTK+ theme is changed (at least in 3.4, so they might have back ported that to 3.3.3).

What you can do is go to tools>options>view and choose another theme (such as galaxy). If you don't have that theme, then you need to install the other LibreOffice icon themes (called styles) from the Software Centre or synaptic.