# LibreOffice 5.3.0.3 update on Ubuntu 14.04 has aditional menu bar and no integration in Unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, libreoffice

Updating LibreOffice 5.3.0.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 get the seemingly regressive appearance shown below:

[menubar and oldfashion icons in LibreOffice and Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuOOL.png)

Buttons are old fashioned, there is an additional menubar, and there is no integration in Unity, the top bar only serves for displaying the name of the file, and do not have menus, as in all Unity/Ubuntu application windows.

Solutions around the menubar issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256837/libreoffice-4-0s-menu-bar-is-not-integrated-with-unity?rq=1)  and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51102/how-to-get-back-the-application-menu-for-libreoffice-after-an-update?rq=1) do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following instruction solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk
```

And then relaunch LibreOffice